# How to merge different column under one column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe which is sparsed and something like this,

```
 Conti_mV_XSCI_140|Conti_mV_XSCI_12|Conti_mV_XSCI_76|Conti_mV_XSCO_11|Conti_mV_XSCO_203|Conti_mV_XSCO_75
        1         | nan            | nan            | 12             | nan             | nan
        nan       | 22             | nan            | nan            | 13              | nan
        nan       | nan            | 9              | nan            | nan             | 31
```

As you can see, **XSCI** is present in 3 header names, only thing is a random number(_140, _12, _76) is added which makes them different.

This is not correct. The column names should be like this - **Conti_mV_XSCI, Conti_mV_XSCO**.
and the final column name(without any random number), should be having values from all the three columns it was spread to(for example - xsci was xsci_140, xsci_12,xsci_76) like that.

The final dataframe should look something like this -

```
Conti_mV_XSCI| Conti_mV_XSCO
1            |  12
22           |  13
99           |  31
```

If you notice, the first value of XSCI comes from the first XSCI_140, second value comes from the second column with XSCI and so on. This is same for XSCO as well.

The issue is, I have to do this for all the columns starting with certain value, like - **"Conti_mV,"IDD_PowerUp_mA"** etc

**My issue:**

I am having a hard time cleaning out the header names because as soon as I remove the random number from the last, it throws an error of columns being duplicate, also it is not elegant

It would be a great help if anyone can help me. Please comment if anything is not clear here.

I need a new dataframe with one column(where there were 3) and combine the data from them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First if necessary convert all columns to numeric:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

If need grouping by column names splited with right side and selected first values:

```
df = df.groupby(lambda x: x.rsplit('_', 1)[0], axis=1).sum()
print (df)
   Conti_mV_XSCI  Conti_mV_XSCO
0            1.0           12.0
1           22.0           13.0
2            9.0           31.0
```

If need filter columns manually:

```
df['Conti_mV_XSCI'] = df.filter(like='XSCI').sum(axis=1)
df['Conti_mV_XSCO'] = df.filter(like='XSCO').sum(axis=1)
```

EDIT: One idea for sum only columns specified in list of starts of columns names:

```
cols = ['IOZH_Pat_uA', 'IOZL_Pat_uA', 'Power_Short_uA', 'IDDQ_uA']

for c in cols:
    # here ^ is for start of string
    columns = df.filter(regex=f'^{c}')
    df[c] = columns.sum(axis=1)
    df = df.drop(columns, axis=1)
print (df)
```

Comment: This is a much faster solution, the groupby  particularly

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot. This works like charm. I believe the above code with groupby works for all the column, right ? Can you please suggest some way that it would only work if the header has certain prefixes, like "Conti_mV", "IDD_PowerUp_mA" etc. Which I can maybe pass in a list or some dictionary and it would do that only for that column? I am not sure if it is even possible. Can you please help here as well?

Comment: @KartikMehra - Fortunately here is easy way solve it. Before `df = df.groupby(lambda x: x.rsplit('_', 1)[0], axis=1).sum()` convert all columns which cannot be used for grouping to index like `df = df.set_index(["Conti_mV", "IDD_PowerUp_mA"]).groupby(lambda x: x.rsplit('_', 1)[0], axis=1).sum()`

Comment: I am not sure if I really got what you suggested me to do but here's what I did and the outcome.

I made a list of the prefixes(like "Conti_mV" etc)
column_list = list(dictionary.keys())
print(column_list)
>Outputs a list, ['IOZH_Pat_uA', 'IOZL_Pat_uA', 'Power_Short_uA', 'IDDQ_uA']
Now,
df_raw_m40C = df_raw_m40C.set_index(column_list).groupby(lambda x: x.rsplit('_', 1)[0], axis=1).sum()

This throws, KeyError: 'IOZH_Pat_uA'.

I think it is due to the fact that before groupby and making a new column, there is no header with this name. I am sorry if there any gap with understanding.

Comment: @KartikMehra - Now I am confused a bit, `['IOZH_Pat_uA', 'IOZL_Pat_uA', 'Power_Short_uA', 'IDDQ_uA']` are prefixes like `Conti_mV_XSCI, Conti_mV_XSCO` in sample data?

Comment: My apologies for not being able to explain properly. So basically there will be multiple columns starting with a certain prefix, for example - There are columns Conti_mV_XSCI_76 ,Conti_mV_XSCO_11 and many more(there will be 2 more columns with XSCI and XSCO but same prefix Conti_mV). Since conti_mV is in our prefix list, all the columns(XSCIs and XSCOs and maybe some others too gets treated). 

Similarly there will be many columns with IOZH_Pat_uA also like IOZH_Pat_uA_ADBUS3_229, IOZH_Pat_uA_ADBUS4_177 etc.

As you can see, IOZH_pat is there in these two name

....part 1/2

Comment: ... part 2/2

So these columns are merged.

IOZH_Pat_uA_ADBUS3_229 with other two IOZH_Pat_uA_ADBUS3_xx,IOZH_Pat_uA_ADBUS3_xxx and IOZH_Pat_uA_ADBUS4_177 with other IOZH_Pat_uA_ADBUS4_yy , IOZH_Pat_uA_ADBUS4_yz

Comment: ..
The only criteria is, if any header name starts with any value in the prefix list, it should be treated. How it should be treated? - Take the first part(omitting the random number from last, make it as a column and fill the data from other 2 header), like you already solved.

Comment: Conti_mV_XSCI, Conti_mV_XSCO are not the prefixes actually. The prefix is the Conti_mv. Since the Conti_mV_XSCI and XSCO start with Conti_mV, they are treated and made a new column.

Comment: @KartikMehra - So finally are 4 columns  - `['IOZH_Pat_uA', 'IOZL_Pat_uA', 'Power_Short_uA', 'IDDQ_uA']` ?

Comment: @KartikMehra - Answer was edited. Last rows.

Comment: @jezrael No. There wont be these 4 columns. So, IOZH_Pat_uA and IOZL_Pat_uA are the prefixes and there could be many column starting with them, for example IPZH_Pat_uA_ADBUS0_1,'IOZH_Pat_uA_ADBUS0_210', 'IOZH_Pat_uA_ADBUS1_168', 'IOZH_Pat_uA_ADBUS1_40', 'IOZH_Pat_uA_ADBUS1_104', 'IOZH_Pat_uA_ADBUS1_232'.

We need to find all the columns from dataframe starting with IOZH_pat_uA(or whatever we have in prefix list) and as you can see the ADBUS1 example, IOZH_Pat_uA_ADBUS1_168, 'IOZH_Pat_uA_ADBUS1_40', 'IOZH_Pat_uA_ADBUS1_104','IOZH_Pat_uA_ADBUS1_232' should combine and become IOZH_Pat_uA_ADBUS1

Comment: I think the first version of your answer was the closest to what I wanted. Just needed some tweaking. Let me play with it, because just a small modification to that is required. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I think the group by should do it with a tweak. Possibly write a function that splits with a regex instead, where the delimiter is `\d+`. The pivot longer fn can do this , however for your use case the group by is so much better and faster

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
df['Conti_mV_XSCI']=df.filter(regex='XSCI').sum()
df['Conti_mV_XSCO']=df.filter(regex='XSCO').sum()
```

edit:

you can fillna with zeroes before the above operations.

```
df=df.fillna(0)
```

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately the new column is all nan

Comment: Thank you so much. +1

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html); at the moment you have to install the latest development version from [github](https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor)

```
# install the latest dev version of pyjanitor
# pip install git+https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor.git
 import janitor

(df.pivot_longer(names_to=".value", 
                 names_pattern=r"(.+)_\d+")
   .dropna())


  Conti_mV_XSCI Conti_mV_XSCO
0    1.0        12.0
4    22.0       13.0
8    9.0        31.0
```

The code looks for values that match a pattern in the group, and returns those values with the header.

Answer (score 1):

This will add a column `Conti_mV_XSCI` with the first non-nan entry for any column whose name begins with `Conti_mV_XSCI`

```py
from math import isnan

df['Conti_mV_XSCI'] =  df.filter(regex=("Conti_mV_XSCI.*")).apply(lambda row: [_ for _ in row if not isnan(_)][0], axis=1)
```